# Cant declare a QWidget because virtual functions are pure

Tags: c++, qt, function, virtual, abstract

I'm trying to make use of interfaces in Qt/C++, but I keep getting a compile error which makes no sense to me, because I have implemented the virtual functions in the derived class. So I was hoping for some help :) Oh yeah, and the compile error is "cannot declare variable 'w' to be of abstract type 'Widget' because the following virtual functions are pure within 'Widget': startGame(), getBoard(), gameFinished().

Main.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

ADTType.h

```
#ifndef ADTTYPE_H
#define ADTTYPE_H
class ADTType
{
public:
    virtual void startGame() = 0;
    virtual void getBoard() = 0;
    virtual void gameFinished() = 0;
    virtual ~ADTType() {}
};
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(ADTType, "ADTType")
#endif // ADTTYPE_H
```

Widget.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QSignalMapper>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include "ADTType.h"

class Widget : public QWidget,
        public ADTType
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES(ADTType)

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

private:
    QHBoxLayout * mainLayout;
    QPushButton * startButton;
    QPushButton * buttons[10];
    QSignalMapper * map;
};
#endif // WIDGET_H
```

Widget.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{}

Widget::~Widget()
{}
void Widget::startGame() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
             buttons[i]->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color: normal}");
    }
    setButtons(true);
    startButton->setDisabled(true);
}

void Widget::getBoard() {

    bool * cells = game->getCells();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (!cells[i]) {
             buttons[i]->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color: red}");
             buttons[i]->setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}

void Widget::gameFinished() {

    int answer = game->getAnswer();
    buttons[answer]->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color: green}");
    setButtons(false);
    game->reset();
    QMessageBox::information(this,tr("Finito"),tr("You found it."),
                             QMessageBox::Ok);
    startButton->setEnabled(true);
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Widget : public QWidget,
    public ADTType
```

So `Widget` inherits from the abstract class `ADTType`. However, you don't declare the overrides (`startGame()` etc) in your `Widget` class, but you only define them in the `Widget.cpp` file. You also need to declare them in the `Widget.h` class header

```
// need these declarations inside the class Widget in Widget.h
virtual void startGame();
virtual void getBoard();
virtual void gameFinished();
```

Minimal example [here](http://ideone.com/tidDkp).

Comment: Okay, that's really weird, because that thought dawned on me earlier. So I tried to do that. But it didn't work then. But now it works.....  But just to be clear, I dont need to write override in the declaration as such "void startGame() override;", but just as "void startGame();", right?

Comment: @user1784297 you may use `override` only in the header, to make sure you override the function (and not hide it via a redeclaration). `override` [is a new `C++11` keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) used to enforce overriding and detect hiding at compile time. I suggest you use it if compiling with C++11 support.

Answer (score 1):

You derived `ADTType` abstract class from the `Widget` so you need to override pure virtual functions in the `Widget` class otherwise it also will become abstract.

```
class Widget : public QWidget,
     public ADTType
{
  ...
  void startGame() { ... }
  void getBoard() { ... }
  void gameFinished() { ... }
};
```

Comment: I'm 99% sure I tried that earlier, but I must have done something wrong when I tried it. Yeah, cause I wasnt sure wether to "redeclare"/override or not in the header.